# How to query JSON derived data like XPath for XML?

Tags: json, perl, path

How can I query `JSON` derived data in the same way as using `XPath` to query `XML`?

For example, if I have the following data, how can I get the `databaseId` where `name` equals `Law Society of New Holland`?

```
$VAR1   =   [    
                {
                     'name' => 'Provincial Court of Stratton and Smythe',
                     'jurisdiction' => 'ab',
                     'databaseId' => 'pcss'
                },
                {
                     'name' => 'Law Society of New Holland',
                     'jurisdiction' => 'cd',
                     'databaseId' => 'lsnh'
                },
                {
                     'name' => 'General Protection Tribunal',
                     'jurisdiction' => 'de',
                     'databaseId' => 'gpt'
                }
            ];
```

Comment: perl really could do with a solid implementation of `jq`.

Comment: @Sobrique: There's a slightly-documented C API for jq, so it should be possible. I'll take a look some time.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the grep (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and map (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) functions in perl. Like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;

my @t   =   (    
                {
                     'name' => 'Provincial Court of Stratton and Smythe',
                     'jurisdiction' => 'ab',
                     'databaseId' => 'pcss'
                },
                {
                     'name' => 'Law Society of New Holland',
                     'jurisdiction' => 'cd',
                     'databaseId' => 'lsnh'
                },
                {
                     'name' => 'General Protection Tribunal',
                     'jurisdiction' => 'de',
                     'databaseId' => 'gpt'
                }
            );

#Just to prove the data is as we think it should be
print "\nPrint Original data:\n";
print Data::Dumper::Dumper( @t);
print "\n"; 

#now filter to the ones that match the name we want
my @foo = grep($_->{'name'} eq 'Law Society of New Holland' , @t);  
print "\nPrint filtered data:\n";
print Data::Dumper::Dumper( @foo);
print "\n"; 

#now only list the databaseid's using the map function
my @bar = map { $_->{'databaseId'} } @foo; 

print "\nPrint only ids:\n"; 
print Data::Dumper::Dumper( @bar);
print "\n";
```

Basically you use the grep to filter the data down, and the map to convert it into an array of only ids. You could even make it a one liner. I've left it a bit longer so it's easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

JSON::Path
http://search.cpan.org/~tobyink/JSON-Path-0.205/lib/JSON/Path.pm

> This module implements JSONPath, an XPath-like language for
>   searching JSON-like structures.
>
> JSONPath is described at http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#Install JSON::Path
# I used sudo cpan install JSON::Path
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::Path;
use Data::Dumper;

# NOTE: The stuff between "?(" and ")" is a Perl expression that must return a boolean, used to filter results.
# As arbitrary Perl may be used, this is clearly quite dangerous unless used in a controlled environment.
# Thus, it's disabled by default. This enables it.
$JSON::Path::Safe = 0;

# You can read in your json however you want to something in this form.
my $data = [
            {
                 'name' => 'Provincial Court of Stratton and Smythe',
                 'jurisdiction' => 'ab',
                 'databaseId' => 'pcss'
            },
            {
                 'name' => 'Law Society of New Holland',
                 'jurisdiction' => 'cd',
                 'databaseId' => 'lsnh'
            },
            {
                 'name' => 'General Protection Tribunal',
                 'jurisdiction' => 'de',
                 'databaseId' => 'gpt',
                 'price' => 1
            }
        ];

# We escape the ' around the name.
# Security warning: This evals perl code DO NOT let users input this search string! (At least not without strict validation).
my $jpath = JSON::Path->new('$[?($_->{name} eq \'Law Society of New Holland\')].databaseId');
my @databaseIds = $jpath->values($data);

print "Your database Ids are:\n";
print Dumper(@databaseIds)."\n";
```

Caution! Consider the risk of this evaluating perl for the condition filter.

Much better to use a grep and map unless you are sure it will not have bad input.